# Mysql - Find "-" and Append "AM" & "PM" Intelligently - If AM, PM is not appended

Tags: mysql

My Sql Query looks like this:

```
SELECT monday 
FROM   `restaurantslive`
```

And the results are

[image]

What I am trying to do is Append "AM" and "PM" after the minutes, example one of the record is

```
6:30–10:30AM, 11:30AM–2PM, 5:30–10:30PM
```

I am trying to make the record to look like the following

```
6:30AM–10:30AM, 11:30AM–2PM, 5:30PM–10:30PM
```

Notice the AM and PM added after 6:30 and 5:30 respectively.

What I tried is this

```
SELECT CONCAT(Monday , 'AM'), FROM `RestaurantsLIVE`
```

But the problem is it appends AM at last which is not the desired result.

Comment: I think you'll come to regret storing this data as a string. Change it to datetime while you have the chance

Comment: @CaiusJard Unfortunately, I cannot do any changes in the data storage, it is supplied by someone with only access to Select statements.

Comment: If source is `6:30–10:30PM`, how to know if 6:30 is AM or PM?  It can be both!

Comment: @DanB Good point, I am trying to work out some logic.. which makes sense, example if there are multiple opening timings in a restaurant (as shown in my example)then split records by comma separator. but again it has limitations.. .

Comment: and what query did they run to get this result? Senseless messing with this databas prsented if it is stored differently and can be utilised more effectively by retrieving it in a different format

Answer (score 0):

```
  select case when right(last,2) = 'AM' then concat(first,'AM-',last)
  when right(last,2) = 'PM' then concat(first,'PM-',last) else concat(first,last) 
  end as monday
        from(
        select if(
                locate('–', monday) > 0,
                substring(monday, 1, locate('–', monday) - 1),
                monday
            ) as first,
            if(
                locate('–', monday) > 0,
                substring(monday, locate('–', monday) + 1),
                null
            ) as last from restaurantslive
            ) temp;
```

Please check with this query. The sub query splits the string into two 
  with '-', and then evaluates AM or PM accordingly

Comment: I tried it says Unexpected keywords near "as", Un expected token Monday" http://prntscr.com/liv6z3